# Arduino HID Project Keyboard Array

Tags: c++, arduino, keyboard, hid, custom-keyboard

I'm currently trying to write code for a keyboard I'm building, but I'm having a lot of trouble on one particular issue. I need to write an array for they keyboard, but it just doesn't work the way I'm expecting it to. Modifier keys work when I use them in the Keyboard.press function, but not when I call them from the array in the `Keyboard.press` function for some reason. For example, if I do `Keyboard.press(KEY_SPACE)` it works fine, but `Keyboard.press(keys[0][0])` outputs , for some reason even though keys[0][0] = KEY_SPACE. The thing is the J and K are working fine, it's specifically the ones formatted as KEY_ that aren't working well

I'm using the HID Project library from Nicohood. When I use the standard arduino keyboard library it works fine, it's just I need to use the HID Project library.

```
#include <HID-Project.h>
#include <HID-Settings.h>



#include <Adafruit_MCP23017.h>

Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp;
byte inputs[] = {4,5,6,7,8,9};
const int inCount = sizeof(inputs)/sizeof(inputs[0]);
byte outputs[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
const int outCount = sizeof(outputs)/sizeof(outputs[0]);

char keys[2][2] = {
  {KEY_SPACE,'j'},
  {'k',KEY_LEFT_SHIFT}
  };

bool keysDown[2][2] = {
  {false, false},
  {false, false}
};

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  
  mcp.begin();
  for(int i=0; i<outCount; i++){    //declaring all the outputs and setting them high
    mcp.pinMode(outputs[i],OUTPUT);
    mcp.digitalWrite(outputs[i],LOW);
  }
  for(int i=0; i<inCount; i++){     //declaring all the inputs and activating the internal pullup resistor
    pinMode(inputs[i],INPUT_PULLUP);
  }
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Keyboard.begin();
}


  
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  keyCheck();
  

}

void keyCheck()
{
  for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
    mcp.digitalWrite(outputs[i],LOW);
    for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
      if(digitalRead(inputs[j]) == LOW && keysDown[i][j] == false)
      {      
        Serial.print("Row: ");
        Serial.print(i);
        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("Col: ");
        Serial.print(j);
        Serial.println();
        Serial.print(keys[i][j]);
        Serial.println();
        Keyboard.press(keys[i][j]);
        Serial.println();
        keysDown[i][j] = true;
        Serial.print("KeysDown set to true");
        Serial.println();
      }else if(digitalRead(inputs[j]) == HIGH && keysDown[i][j] == true)
      {
        Serial.print("keysdown set to false");
        Serial.println();
        Keyboard.release(keys[i][j]);
        keysDown[i][j] = false;
      }
      delay(1);
    }
    mcp.digitalWrite(outputs[i], HIGH);
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been trying to figure this out for over a month, and it's been really frustrating as everything else is finished, it's just this one specific issue has been blocking the whole project. Thanks for your time.

Comment: In `setup()`...  You should set outputs high by calling `digitalWrite(inputs[i],HIGH);`  rght before calling `pinMode(inputs[i],INPUT_PULLUP);`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may have been tricked by your debug output format.

The KEY_SPACE constant has a value of decimal 44 (hex 2C) which is the ASCII code point for a comma. You are writing this value via the Serial class to your terminal, so you see a comma. Then you are sending it again via the Keyboard class, which dutifully displays the (invisible) space.

A convention I use to avoid this kind of confusion is to always enclose variable content in debug output with begin/end markers - for example, `printf("row <%d> col <%d> char <%s>", i, j, key[i, j])` ... or similar.

Comment: It's not just in the debug output. If I just open a note pad every other character works fine but KEY_SPACE in the array still outputs as a ,

Comment: ok, I should have read the docs more closely. The Keyboard.press() method only accepts a subset of ASCII characters, plus a few so-called ["keyboard modifiers"](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/keyboardmodifiers) such as `KEY_LEFT_SHIFT`, but `KEY_SPACE` is not one of the allowable modifiers, so I would suggest simply replacing `KEY_SPACE` in your array with a literal space: `' '`. If that resolves your issue then I'll update my answer accordingly.